# Why lighthouse plugin doesn't recognize service-worker in Angular 6 app?

Tags: angular, service-worker, angular-service-worker, lighthouse, angular-pwa

I used the Angular 6 CLI to generate and register the service-worker in the application, when I manually enable offline mode, the service-worker job is correct, but as soon as I try to audit using the lighthouse, it tells me that the service worker is not registered.

[image]

Comment: Can you see your worker in Chrome Devtools/Application->Service workers tab without a Lighthouse?

Comment: Yeah, it's rigistered

Comment: Have you tried following [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/offline/#0) guide? It explains how to tune your service worker to return 200 when offline. Also [docs](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/registered-service-worker) should give you  a pretty decent start. If it doesn't work, could you share your service worker code. It might give some more insight on what's going on.

Comment: I just use Angular 6 CLI for generate service-worker, like I see he is registered, but any way plugin say to me like it's not working

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I had the same issue. It initially worked but once I added a lazy load child module, the test failed and complained service worker not registered. But the website still loads even if I turned off the server.

Answer (score 0):

It's mostly because you might be using angularfire2.

This can be solved by adding the below in main.ts file

```
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(() => {
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && environment.production) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('ngsw-worker.js');
    }
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Hope it helps.